# Rackspace Repose for rate limiting

Tags: java, rest, throttling

I checked out [repose](http://openrepose.org/) for rate limiting. Since this works for distributed applications, so I found it very helpful for my purpose as we are having a distributed application. But I am finding it really difficult to test it on my local machine. I followed one of the tutorial provided [here](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=3845). But this does not works for me. Also, I am using DropWizard Framework which uses Jetty as Server.

Please provide some tutorials for repose for testing it on local.

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevant for you, but if anyone else is search for this information, the documentation for local setup/debugging can be found here: http://www.openrepose.org/versions/8.5.0.1/recipes/vagrant.html with Vagrant or http://www.openrepose.org/versions/8.5.0.1/recipes/docker.html with Docker.